# TypeScript: Exclude Union String Literal Value from Interface Key

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have an interface like this.

```
interface ITest {
  key1?: string;
  key2?: 'apple' | 'orange' | 'cherry' | 'grape';
}
```

**Question**

How can I extend `ITest` while excluding specific string literal values from the `key2` union type?

I know I could use `Exclude` to remove `key2` entirely, but how could I keep `key2` but exclude specific values from its union type?

I have tried something like but with no luck. Not sure if this is possible with utility classes only without creating a separate `Fruit` type, for example and using `Exclude` on it.

```
Exclude<Pick<ITest, 'key2'>, 'apple' | 'grape'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- take all properties except key2
- add key2 with excluded elements

```ts
interface ITest {
  key1?: string;
  key2?: 'apple' | 'orange' | 'cherry' | 'grape';
}

type I2 = Omit<ITest, 'key2'> & {
  key2?: Exclude<ITest['key2'], 'apple' | 'grape'>
}

// alternative way
type I3 =  { 
  [P in keyof ITest]: P extends 'key2' 
  ? Exclude<ITest['key2'], 'apple' | 'grape'> 
  : ITest[P] 
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUIGczIN4BQyyA1hAJ4CMA-AFzI5SgDmA3EaRQEx3IDkcAA6CANhD7IAPvwD2UOCGbip-BAAtoUchOl9m8wePYBfAgTDlDaLsgC8yAPIBbYGAA8GbGAA0-MuS4+AD5kADJ8Dn8eegBRAA8EEQBXABMID0wcAG0+KL4AXV8BYTEdfn0hcSCCUwIEGRAcZGAuelQbe0Jif0p6Pha+b0juPrkFJT4aoA)

Comment: Awesome! I had no idea about the bracket notation option. Is there a way to do it all at once, and not re-add the key to the new interface? (Mostly just curious now)

Comment: @Yuschick added another way to code it

Comment: Thanks for the example. I think I prefer your first approach, but I appreciate you showing me the alternative I was curious about.